# I Can't login as root with su command, but I can with SSH

Tags: centos, login, authentication, su

How is it possible that I cannot log in as root by `su root` or `su` (I get incorrect password error), *but* I can log in by `ssh root@localhost` or `ssh root@my_local_IP` with the same password?

I'm using CentOS 6.4.

---

#### *Update1* :

```
cat /etc/pam.d/su
```

gives:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth       sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        include     system-auth
account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account     include     system-auth
password    include     system-auth
session     include     system-auth
session     optional    pam_xauth.so
```

#### *Update2* :

```
$ sudo grep su /var/log/secure | grep -v sudo
```

gives :

```
Feb 23 13:12:17 fallah su: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure;
logname=fallah uid=501 euid=501 tty=pts/0 ruser=fallah rhost=  user=root
```

repeated about 20 times.

Comment: Try clearing out the file `/etc/securetty` (`cp /etc/securetty{,.old}; : > /etc/securetty`). If that still doesn't work, provide the content of `/etc/pam.d/su`.

Comment: no it doesn't work .

Comment: I provided the content of `/etc/pam.d/su` in the queston

Comment: @Patrick Look at the update please

Comment: I did, but I'm not seeing anything that would cause a problem. Appreciate the info though, at least rules out some possibilities. Someone else will probably have some more ideas.

Comment: Surely with `ssh 192.168.1.218` you are just logging in as yourself? To log in as root via `ssh` would normally need `ssh root@192.168.1.218` or `ssh root@localhost`.

Comment: @Graeme, No, I'm sorry, I tried ssh root@192.168.1.218, I forgot to mention in my question, updated

Comment: Get the PID (12345) of your shell (`echo $$`), open (e.g. via `ssh`) a root shell (necessary for tracing SUID binaries) and start `strace` for that shell: `strace -o su.strace -p 12345 -f` and look for strange errors before the error message. Or copy the last 30 lines before the error message into your question if you are not familiar with that kind of output.

Comment: @HaukeLaging it says `Process 11736 attached - interrupt to quit`

Comment: @AlirezaFallah Of course, the output is written to the file `su.strace`. So after the `su` error message you quit `strace` and check the log file.

Comment: @HaukeLaging : the content of `su.strace` file is `11736 waitpid(-1,  <unfinished ...>`

Comment: @AlirezaFallah That is hard to believe. Are you sure you have started `strace` before you startet `su`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging , I swear I'm sure ;)

Comment: Could you please post the output of `ls -l /bin/su` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - `-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 30092 Jun 22  2012 /bin/su`

Comment: OK, that's the reason it isn't working. /bin/su needs to have its setuid bit on so that when ordinary (non-root) users use it, it will have access to the password list in /etc/shadow. Type, as root, `chmod 4755 /bin/su` to fix this.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, wow, It worked like a charm, can you please post it as answer so I can accept it ? and please provide some more explanation about the problem, thanks .

Comment: Sure. I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: I see this is a bit old now, but this always works for me: `su -`

Comment: This answer led me to solving my issue via `sed -Ei 's/(.*pam_deny.so)/#\1/' /etc/pam.d/su` because the last line in `/etc/pam.d/su` was `auth requisite pam_deny.so`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your comment, you said that `/bin/su` has the following mode/owner:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 30092 Jun 22 2012 /bin/su
```

There are two problems here.

- it needs to have the set-uid bit turned on, so that it always runs with root permissions, otherwise when an ordinary (non-root) user runs it, it will not have access to the password info in `/etc/shadow` nor the ability to set the userid to the desired new user.
- it ought to have the `group` and `other` write bits turned off, so that other users cannot alter it.

To fix this, login as `root` - you said you can do this with `ssh`- and type

```
chmod 4755 /bin/su
```

or, alternatively,

```
chmod u+s,g-w,o-w /bin/su
```

(The [standards document for chmod](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) goes into more detail about what kinds of arguments it takes.)
This will restore the mode bits to the way they were when the operating system was first installed. When you list this file, it ought to look like this:

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 30092 Jun 22 2012 /bin/su
```

As @G-Man noted, files that are mode 777 could be overwritten by untrusted users, and if that's the case, you may want to reinstall them from the distribution medium or backups.

Comment: I usually use like : `chmod 755 /bin/su` , what is the extra ***4*** for ?

Comment: The `4` in the first position represents the set-uid permission. I've edited my answer to add an alternative way to use chmod using symbolic names for the permission bits. Hopefully that will be more clear.

Comment: thank you very very much. I now figured out that I executed the `chmod -R 777 /bin` by mistake, and that's why I have been cursed :D

Comment: I also asked  [**another question**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117013/reverse-a-chmod-command-on-a-directory), would you please see it, maybe you know the answer.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html describes how to use `rpm` to restore file permissions, but I have not tried it.

Comment: I also recommend reinstalling the package containing `su` as soon as possibly, because if `su` has been world writable for any length of time I would no longer trust it to give it setuid permissions...

Comment: Ahh good old ssh, you're a lifesaver, even if su/sudo doesn't work. the ssh works like a charm

Comment: Your answer is incomplete; it should be (0) Login as `root`; (1) `rm /bin/su`; (2) Securely extract/retrieve a good copy of `su` from installation media or a trusted backup (or recompile it from a trusted copy of the source code); (3) Install it in `/bin`; and ***then*** (4) `chmod 4755 /bin/su`. Because, of course, if it’s been 777 for any period of time, it could already have been tampered with.

Comment: @G-man Sure. Thanks. OP noted that everything in `/bin` was accidentally set to 777. If there are untrusted users on the system, then everything should be restored from distribution media. I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 13):

#### 1. wheel group?

This is likely because your useid is not in the `wheel` group. On Red Hat distros you can explicitly disallow users who are not in this group from running the `su` command.

Here's what the `su` PAM configuration looks like by default:

```
$ more /etc/pam.d/su
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth       sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        include     system-auth
account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account     include     system-auth
password    include     system-auth
session     include     system-auth
session     optional    pam_xauth.so
```

This line can limit access to the `su` command to users in the `wheel` group:

```
auth        required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

From the sound of it this is enabled and your userid isn't allowed to operate the `su` command.

SSH works since it goes through a different PAM mechanism. SSH also has it's own facilities for limiting access to root logins too. Root logins is typically permitted by default, at least on most of the Red Hat distros:

```
$ sudo grep PermitRoot /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
#PermitRootLogin yes
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
```

Even though the above is commented out, it's the default, and is how OpenSSH shows it's the default setting in the configs.

**Working with this?**

If your system is configured like this, you can add your username to the `wheel` group.

```
$ useradd -G wheel saml
```

After logging out and back in:

```
$ groups
saml wheel
```

**NOTE:** My userid is "saml" above.

#### 2. Permissions right on su?

Check that the executable is owned by root.

```
$ type -a su
su is /usr/bin/su
su is /bin/su

$ ls -l /usr/bin/su /bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 32064 Jan 13 06:31 /bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 32064 Jan 13 06:31 /usr/bin/su
```

Also confirm that the executables have their `s` bits enabled. This makes them setuid, so that when they're executed they run as their own, root.

#### 3. What do the logs say?

When you attempt to do the `su -` command you should see entries in `/var/log/secure` about the attempt.

```
$ sudo grep su /var/log/secure | grep -v sudo
Feb 23 23:31:26 greeneggs su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by saml(uid=0)
Feb 24 00:27:32 greeneggs su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user root
Feb 24 01:34:12 greeneggs su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by saml(uid=1000)
Feb 24 01:34:26 greeneggs su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user root
```

Consult this log to see if you get any additional info.

#### 4. Are you sure the password isn't the problem?

When I attempt to login using `su -` I get the following when I give it an incorrect password:

```
$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
$
```

I'd try creating another account and seeing if this secondary account can run `su -` successfully.

Comment: thank you by your great answer, what I tried after reading your answer : `usermod -a -G wheel my_username` , and the result of `groups` is `fallah wheel`. So the result of `cat /etc/pam.d/su` is now in my question, AND, again I'm not able to log in as root by su command !!!

Comment: this is the last line of `/var/log/secure` : `Feb 24 10:19:45 fallah su: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=fallah uid=501 euid=501 tty=pts/2 ruser=fallah rhost=  user=root`

Comment: and this line is repeated about 20 times in `/var/log/secure`

Comment: 4 : but when I try : `su: incorrect password`  - and the password is correct, because the I can log an with the same password in SSH

Comment: I also tried to login with another account , like `su alireza` , and again the same problem

Comment: @AlirezaFallah - can user "fallah" `su - alireza`?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah - also please try `su -l root`. Notice in my logs I have `su-l:session` whereas you do not. There are 2 files in `pam.d` related to `su`. `/etc/pam.d/su` & `/etc/pam.d/su-l`.

Comment: No he can't `su alireza`, incorrect password

Comment: @AlirezaFallah - can you do this next: `strace -s 2000 -o su.log su - alireza`. After attempting to login and it failing, can you post the output log, `su.log` to pastebin and post the link here?

Comment: This is it : [su.log](http://pastebin.com/PkVvYJwn)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error message like this

```
su: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_tally.so
su: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_tally.so): /lib64/security/pam_tally.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Do this step:

```
ln -s /lib64/security/pam_tally2.so /lib64/security/pam_tally.so
```

Then try su. It should work.