# Reverse a chmod command on a directory

Tags: centos, chmod

Is there a way to undo a `chmod` command on a directory in **CentOS** ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple,
No it's not and if you still get the list of your authorization, then you can only restore them through a script or manually.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way how to revert chmod changes is from backup. Or maybe if these files come from an rpm package use `rpm --setperms`.

Comment: Backup is also an option I forget this one I never save file permission in my backups :D now I see I should

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is part of the system or an installed package managed by `rpm` you can find out which package it is part of with `rpm -qf /directory` and then can try `rpm -qV <package>` (verify) to see what the installed permissions settings were. You can then revert to those with `chmod` manually or with `rpm --setperms` as stderr mentioned.